Book about rune chalk where the characters could create magic from drawing symbols on the ground
The book I’m just to identify is a fiction book about time magic. I don’t remember the main character and anything but I could have sworn the book was called something along the lines of “The Arithmetic”.
It’s about rune chalk where the characters could create magic from drawing symbols on the ground. At age 15 or 16, each teenager would take nectar or a drink of some sort that would reveal if the characters would conjure magic. The main character took it but was informally not able to conjure magic but the book mentioned that the vision he had showed him there was a more sinister way to obtain the power to create magic. The main character also discovered some new spells when reviewing I believe some books on his father(who might have died or disappeared).
I apologize for the vague details but I read this 5-7 years ago  and have been trying to finish this series. Any help is much appreciated as when I look up the title, I keep getting recommendations for The Devil's Arithmetic which I know for sure is not it. Thanks.

The Rithmatist, Sanderson

@Radhil: Do you want to take it?

@Radhil: If you want to take some or all of my answer tomorrow, I will withdraw mine.

@JeronimoGonzalez: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

@FuzzyBoots no worries, had no time to look up deets

As per Radhil's comment, this is likely The Rithmatist by Brandon Sanderson.

The world in which The Rithmatist is set is similar to the recent past of our own but with complex geared machinery, known as "springwork", taking the role of technologies that would, in reality, usually be powered by electricity or steam.
At 8 years old, children undergo a religious ceremony known as Inception, during which the child's fate is decided: fewer than 1 in 1000 are chosen to become Rithmatists.
Rithmatists are warriors. They use geometric patterns of chalk (Lines) to perform magic with physical effects. Lines may shield a user, attack an opponent or animate a creature known as a Chalkling which will do the Rithmatist's bidding.
Rithmatists are humanity's primary defence against the mysterious Wild Chalklings. After graduating, a Rithmatist is expected to spend time in Nebrask actively using their gift and training to wage war, protecting the United American Isles from the threat of Wild Chalklings escaping The Tower.
The story mainly takes place at Armedius Academy, one of 8 schools that trains and teaches Rithmatists, alongside non-Rithmatists with rich or important families.

....

The Rithmatist follows the story of Joel, a teenage boy who is enrolled at and lives on the campus of Armedius Academy. He is not a Rithmatist, yet is interested in the study of Rithmatist power. Joel, eager to know more about Rithmatics, helps a professor at Armedius Academy when students of the school start disappearing—kidnapped and presumed dead.

